# React -Redirect From External Website to react app

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router

I am trying build a feature to my app which is to allow users to reset their account password , everything seems to working but one problem that I have is that once I send a link to their email and they click on the link the app dose not redirect them to the correct page,
here is my code

front-end react route: (this route should handle loading the correct page)

```
 <Route path="/resetPassword/:token" exact component={ResetPassword} />
```

backend reset url: (the user will click on this link to go back to my app)

```
const resetURL = `https://my.domain.com/resetPassword/${resetToken}`;
```

I was looking here and there but all the solutions is more about doing the revers thing which is to take the user from our app to external link but I want the revers.

any help , thanks in advance for any help
appreciate your time.

Comment: sorry but what exactly is the issue? is the problem that going to that route doesn't render your `ResetPassword` component? what happens if you just navigate to `/resetPassword/:token` manually from your browser?

Comment: Hey Tom , thanks for responding, it dose not render the ResetPassword Component even if I manually typed the url .

Comment: https://developer.android.com/training/app-links

Comment: there is something wrong with your routing set up then if you can't navigate to it normally - can you provide a snippet showing the rest of your routes?

Comment: you are 100% right, I just saw my mistake , its was a wrong implementation for handling route and I fix it , you saved my life Tom , thank you so much , really really appreciate your time.